# List<string> doesn't update the UI when change occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="468" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>



[Serializable()]
public class MYcontainer : INotifyPropertyChanged,ISerializable
{
    private List<MYClass> _items = new List<MYClass>();
    public List<MYClass> Items
    {
        get{ return _items;}
       set { this._items =value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  
}
```

When I add an item to "Items" the UI doesn't update, the binding is working fine, since if I closed the window and opened it again, the new items appear correctly.

What am I doing wrong? I know if I used `ObservableCollection` it will work fine, but shouldn't it work with `List<>`? I already have in another window a string[] property and it update fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to ues `ObservableCollection` you will have to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyCollectionChanged
{

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action));
        }
    }
}
```

However `ObservableCollection` does all this for you, adding all the same logic to your `List<T>` would just create a custom `ObservableCollection`, I see no point in this when MS has alraedy made this for you

Answer (score 4):

It will currently only update if you replace the entire list with a new `List<MyClass>`. Replacing 1 item won't trigger the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

Use an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` instead of a `List<MyClass>`. It's built specifically to handle this issue and notifies WPF whenever the items in the collection change.

It's very comparable to list in other respects so the changes to your code should be minimal (Both List and ObservableCollection implement the `ICollection<T>` interface, so most of the methods are shared).

Comment: when i add an item, i write this  this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");

Comment: I honestly haven't tried this before, but I suspect .NET is being too smart for it's own good and realizing it is still the same List object and not updating. This would line up with your string[] observation, as extending an array would mean making a whole new array, I suspect if you create a `new List<MyClass>` it would actually work (though not being good for performance). Is there a reason you're avoiding ObservableCollection?

Comment: isn't `List<>` better performance in loop than `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Performance difference would be negligible. In fact, I'm relatively sure `ObservableCollection` actually uses a `List` internally for it's data storage. It just adds the notify events, which would slow down updates slightly, but while I haven't benchmarked it I'd be suprised if it slowed reads by a noticable amount.